# How to make web app accessible on the web using WAMP?

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, wamp

I've only just installed WAMP Server 2.2 on my computer running Windows 7, in order to build a web app and make it available online. However, I don't have a clue as to how I do this exactly, being a complete novice. 
Please help.

Comment: Before you ask 'How?', you should as 'Should I?'. The answer to the second question is 'No'. You need to understand the security concerns in opening you web app on WAMP to the internet. It is for **local** development

Comment: Can you outline why you would like to do this? If it's for the learning experience, fine - however if it is to do hosting a bit cheaper, you should find out exactly what hosting costs these days. A starter shared hosting account can be picked up these days for 10GBP/USD per year.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, make sure:

- Your computer is connected directly to the Internet or that any router that is providing NAT for you is forwarding ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) from the Internet facing IP to your computer on the LAN
- Ports 80 and 443 are not blocked by a software firewall on your computer
- Apache is configured to listen on the network interface and now just on localhost

That said, **don't do this**. Residential network connections are not optimal for hosting websites on (and some forbid it). This would require that you leave your computer running all the time. Any security issues with your server could expose your private network to attackers on the Internet.

Buy some third party webhosting instead. Use a locally installed server only for development.

Comment: I'd regard a home internet connection that forbade home servers as "not real internet" and thus wouldn't knowingly sign up to such a service - most ISPs don't care, at least here in the UK afaik. I agree that there is a risk involved to the home user, but would say "do it if you know what you are doing" rather than "don't do it".

Comment: @halfer — Given the question, I suspect the OP doesn't "know what they are doing" :)

Comment: I agree, but answers here are for everyone, rather than just for OPs. But good answer, +1!

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy hosting and move the files from your local machine to a remote server else it won't be accessible on the web.

Check out the [Tizag Hosting Guide](http://www.tizag.com/webhost/) for more info.

WAMP is for local development rather than hosting your site on the web.

Comment: This just one solution. And "You need to buy hosting […] else it won't be accessible on the web." is just wrong.

Comment: I'd also worry about Tizag. I haven't looked at their hosting guide, but the Perl and PHP stuff I've seen there qualifies as "Worse than W3Schools".

Comment: True it won't be accessible on the web, but it's the answer 99.9% of the time, and @Quentin that is a damming review! I'll have to have a full read-through and double check